# Conversion Failure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While running the below query I'm met with the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.' to data type
> int.

I understand that it sees the column value '0.' as numeric but cannot convert to an INT data type. I wanted to ask how I would work around this as I would only like to display the whole numbers in the column.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    wh.Id,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(wh.Uid AS INT) = 1 
    THEN CAST(UID AS INT) 
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Cardholder ID]
FROM  database.dbo.table wh
```

Some examples of the contents of the column are as follows:

```
112
222225
55546
4478
0.)
0.
C/Windows/system.ini
Text here
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function. Use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`. [Is It Time To Stop Using IsNumeric()?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/), [Fifteen Things I Hate About ISNUMERIC](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/), [Stop using ISNUMERIC, it’s (probably) wrong](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/)

Comment: Honestly, however, it also seems like you have much bigger problems in regards to the quality of your data. For a column with the name `Uid` I wouldn't expect to see such a mix of values. Incorrect choice of data type and lack of validation seem to 2 big contributors here.

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('2e0');` tells you all you need to know. Anyway, for the values that are _not_ compatible with `int`, what do you want to show?

Comment: (And to summarize the links, I've written about this before too, `ISNUMERIC()` answers the question "can this value be converted to _ANY_ numeric type?", not the question "can this value be converted to _EVERY_ numeric type?" The difference is subtle, usually, but other times it's a shovel to the side of the head.

Comment: Your example data leaves it unclear as to whether `'42.'` should return `42` or `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `isnumeric()`, I tend to use `try_convert()`.

That said, `try_convert(money,...)` seems to be a little more forgiving.

**Example**

```
Declare @users Table ([UID] varchar(50))  Insert Into @users Values 
 ('112')
,('222225')
,('55546')
,('4478')
,('0.)')
,('0.')
,('C/Windows/system.ini')
,('Text here')
,('4.')

 
Select * 
      ,NewValue = try_convert(int,coalesce(try_convert(money,UID),0))
from @users
```

**Results**

```
UID                     NewValue
112                     112
222225                  222225
55546                   55546
4478                    4478
0.)                     0
0.                      0
C/Windows/system.ini    0
Text here               0
4.                      4
```